# How to pass random length of a function in PHP

Tags: php

I have a bit of code, which generates a random string, however I also want the length of the string to be random.

I have this code right now:

```
$len = rand(0, 50);

function generateRandomString($length = $len) {
    $characters = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

However, this gives me an error saying "Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations". Is there any way of passing a random length value to the function?

Thank you

Comment: Is it ment to be used for security related things ? (generating passwords or tokens and the like) ?

Comment: @Raxi it's meant to test http services in the backend of my function, so whenever the string is generated, it will be used to send an http request to one of the services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. The user can enter a random length and if not provided the function auto generates a random length of its own.

```
function generateRandomString($length = null)
{
    $characters = '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';

    $length = $length ? $length : rand(0, 50);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    return $randomString;
}

var_dump(generateRandomString()); // works
var_dump(generateRandomString(4)); // also works
```

Comment: I also notice you have space between the numbers, is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: yes this is intentional, as I want the generator to have a higher likelihood to generate a string including a space to help testing

Comment: I just tested this, and it works! Thank you so much for you help :)

Comment: You're most welcome